# Internationalizating images in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, image, internationalization, mxml

I have a button in Flex that has mx:skin set to an image, but i want to set it so that when i change the language the image change as well. The code is something like the following:

```
<mx:Button id="btnMain">
    <mx:skin>@Embed(source='main/resources/images/ABA_MAIN_IDLE.png')</mx:skin>
```

The way i handle i18n is by using a class called ConfigI18n that wraps the ResourceManager, and i just have to call it like i would with ResourceManager:

```
<mx:Label text="{ConfigI18n.getInstance().getString('someLabel')}"/>
```

I tried using the i18n within mx:skin but didn't work. Anyone also had the same problem or already did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [IResourceManager.getClass()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/resources/IResourceManager.html#getClass%28%29).

In your resource file (messages.properties, say), embed the image:

```
idleImage=Embed("assets/images/idle.png")
```

Then in your code (using your example, but not sure of skin syntax):

```
<mx:Button id="btnMain">
    <mx:skin>{resourceManager.getClass("messages", "idleImage")}</mx:skin>
</mx:Button>
```